# While passing a variable to another class in java netbeans automatically generating extra zeroes?

Tags: database, variables, jframe, row

When selecting a row in Jtable getting a value to a variable , that variable want to be passed to another JFrame and that JFrame should be open !!
Actually the problem is , while opening the next jFrame two zeroes are generating which hinders the original variable.
*What should be the reason , What must be the solutions ??*

Comment: please give code examples. the minimum we need to understand, or reproduce.

Comment: private void JtableMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {  
 
 if (evt.getClickCount() == 2)  // double click
        {
            nextFrame a = new nextFrame(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
            a.setVisible(true);
         
            int selectedRowIndex = Jtable.getSelectedRow();
       Object selectedObject = (Object) Jtable.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 6);
         
        }
 
 System.out.println(selectedObject);
}
This is the code bugging for a long time !!

Comment: please put the code in your main post (edit it), and use proper code-snipped formatting.

Answer (score 0):

private void JtableMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

```
if (evt.getClickCount() == 2)  // double click
    {
        nextFrame a = new nextFrame(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
        a.setVisible(true);

        int selectedRowIndex = Jtable.getSelectedRow();
        Object selectedObject = (Object) Jtable.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 6);

    }

System.out.println(selectedObject);
```

}